# Why does Ubuntu 10.04 not see my hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, installation, partitioning, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 10.04 64bit to a new machine.

mobo = gigabyte x58a-ud3r
cpu = i7 930
ssd = Kingston 64GB V+
hhd = wd 1tb black

When the installation gets to the prepare partions step, no partitions are listed.  Drives are recognized by BIOS and WinXP setup sees them.

I have also tried Ubuntu 9.10.  It does not see the drives also.

Just searching around I found a suggestion to select "no dmraid" in additional options screen.  This did not seem to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: this harddrive isn't configured in Windows as a Dynamic Disk, is it?  when you boot into the LiveCD, what is the output of **sudo fdisk -l** ?

Comment: sudo fdisk -l outputs nothing. If it helps to know, I did not install Win XP I just went as far into the installation to see that it recognized the disks.

Comment: I think the ubuntu installer might expect the hard drive to have a drive lablel, which is not given to it until it is formated with something. Try formating the whole drive as ext3 or ext4 with a gparted live cd. You can also boot it as a secondary drive on a windows system and format it from there. Then try to install ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a bunch of different BIOS tweaks and Internet suggestions to no avail...

I simply switched all my SATA connections from the SATA 6 Gb/s connectors and connected them to the SATA3 connectors.

This seemed to solve all my problems.  Is this a known issue that Ubuntu does not support SATA 6 GB/s?

Comment: I assume by "SATA6 connectors" you mean the connectors for the SATA 3.0 (?) with 6Gbps link speed via the Marvell SE9128 chip, yes? I suppose it's possible that support for the SE9128 didn't make it into the kernel used for the 10.04 CD. I see a newer kernel is available via update. If you're curious you could upgrade the kernel and then switch the connector of one of your drives back to the 6Gbps SATA port and see if Ubuntu now recognizes it.

Comment: FWIW, the Gigabyte page for your motherboard http://www.gigabyte-usa.com/Products/Motherboard/Products_Overview.aspx?ClassValue=Motherboard&ProductID=3317&ProductName=GA-X58A-UD3R/ has the following cryptic comment at the bottom. "Due to different Linux support condition provided by chipset vendors, please download Linux driver from chipset vendors' website or 3rd party website."

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this at terminal:

$ ls /dev/sd*

If you see the sda1, sdb1, (or whatever your drive is connected as) then you simply need to set up a mount using the mount command, which is straight forward enough as creating a directory and running mount -t < filesystem> < device> < directory> as root.

Comment: ls /dev/sd* produces the following output: ls: cannot access /dev/sd*: no such file or directory

Comment: You might need to be root. Put sudo infront of that.
Also, you can ls /dev/ to see EVERYTHING, maybe when you setup ubuntu you did somewhere where disks aren't registering as sd[a-z][0-9] format...

Comment: Adding sudo outputs the same.  If I ls /dev/ I do not see any sd devices.

Comment: What does sudo fdisk -l output?

Comment: sudo fdisk -l does not output anything